# Find the sum of this series :$ \frac{1}{{1!2009!}} + \frac{1}{{3!2007!}} +  \cdots  + \frac{1}{{1!2009!}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Find the sum of this series :

$$\sum\limits_{\scriptstyle 1 \leqslant x \leqslant 2009  \atop 
  {\scriptstyle x+y=2010 \atop 
  \scriptstyle {\text{  }}x,y{\text{ odd}} }}  {\frac{1}{{x!y!}}}  = \frac{1}{{1!2009!}} + \frac{1}{{3!2007!}} +  \cdots  + \frac{1}{{1!2009!}}$$

I tried converting it into binomial coefficients and I'm getting sort of $\dfrac{2^{2009}}{2009!}$

Please help me.

Comment: Is the general term in the series $\dfrac{1}{{x!}{y!}}$ with $x+y=2010$ and $x$ odd ?

Comment: I too thought so.

Comment: @lhf Edited accordingly.

Comment: Your answer $2^{2009}/2009!$ is correct. What problem are you having?

Comment: @Logan: It’s off by a factor of $2010$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks. I'm not sure how I messed that up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You’ve the right idea. First,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{1004}\frac1{(2k+1)!(2010-2k-1)!}=\frac1{2010!}\sum_{k=0}^{1004}\binom{2010}{2k+1}\;.$$

Now that last summation is simply the number of odd-sized subsets of a set of $2010$ elements. Since half the subsets of any non-empty set have odd cardinality, it’s simply $2^{2009}$. Thus, the desired sum is $$\frac{2^{2009}}{2010!}\;.$$

Answer (score 8):

By cancelling the even terms and doubling up the odd terms and dividing by $2$, the sum is
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2010!}\frac12\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2010}\binom{2010}{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{2010}(-1)^k\binom{2010}{k}\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac{1}{2010!}\frac12\left((1+1)^{2010}-(1-1)^{2010}\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac{2^{2009}}{2010!}
\end{align}
$$